# Настройка локальных компьютеров,учетных записей

Tags: сеть

Уважаемые Пользователи сайта РутКод,Форумчане!Обращаюсь к Вам вот с каким вопросом:на компьтерах(рабочих станциях) подключенных к внутренней сете крупного российского государственного предприятия (в основном все рабочие станции под управление Windows XP) админисратором были оставлены пользователям доступы к выполнению большинства команд, к выполнению cmd.exe и запуску команд через cmd.exe, также оставлена возможность просмотра настроек сети,изменения насроек компьютера,досуп в Панель управления,возможность подсоединения и загрузки с внешних носителей и так далее...Вопрос следующий: чем в худшем случае "стечение обстоятельств" грозит компании данное упущение в правах на локальных машинах. подключенных к внутренней сети, в случае использования этих возможностей злоумышленником.Если можно с примером и последствиями. Интересуют наихудшие варианты развития сбытий

Заранее Вам благодарен.Спасибо!

Comment: > возможность подсоединения и загрузки с внешних носителей при физическом доступе практически нереально запретить загрузку с внешних носителей (можно опечатать, чтобы пароль на биос нельзя было сбросить, но в большинстве случаев есть технический пароль)

Comment: ну не, ограничить конечно же можно и решения для этого есть

Comment: называется - опечатать.

Answer (score 1):

[@danila](/users/450/danila) т.к. сам работаю в банке, то отвечу на Ваш наезд на банковскую сферу:
 1. Ни у одного из директоров (президентов/вицов-/начальников департаментов) нет доступа ко ВСЕМ возможным базам в банке - ибо ему это просто не нужно, да честно говоря и некогда выуживать необходимую инфу (разговаривал со многими it-шниками в др. банках);
 2. Т.к. банки жестко структурированы по-вертикали и основной раздачей прав на действия в различных базах, введение учеток в AD и т.п. задачи занимаются различные отделы IT-департамента (и чаще не в регионах) + еще вся эта бодяга контролируется Департаментом Экономической Безопасности - то в GP уже давно прописаны длины паролей на основании решений, подписанных президентом, и поэтому вышеописанные мной подразделения ср*ть хотели на желание местного (регионального) управляющего, который мучает своего IT-ка (у которого к тому же нет прав на изменение параметров GP), на предмет укорачивания или пустого пароля. Наоборот, накатают служебку президенту от имени директора Департамента IT, по факту чего местечковый управляющий-юморист получит за нарушение инф-безопасности;
 3. Был в такой ситуации. Популярно объяснил как работает эта схема, что прав на изменение этих параметров у меня просто нет. Изменю их на локальной машине - завтра же они вернуться при обновлении GP из домена. Описал возможные последствия. И, сказал, что если он продолжает настаивать, прошу написать письменное распоряжение. После такого демарша управляющий успокоился.

Comment: Нет-нет, уважаемый, на самом деле я просто не так выразился.Мне следовало сказать "одного из,например,банков". Это ни в коем случае не был наезд на банковскую сферу,а всего лишь описание часто встречающейся ситуации.У вас просто напросто есть опыт и уверенность в себе (что, бесспорно, только положительный момент) и вам действительно ср.ть на капризы управляющего (и только плюс вам). Но большинство наших коллег (особенно начинающих) не столь упорны и результат не радует. У меня так же было по молодости, когда в крупных конторах начинал работать.Но тем не менее - дыры в сети, это не редкость.

Comment: про наличие дыр согласен - они могут быть везде. Однако, все-таки описанная Вами ситуация больше подходит для контор разной степени крупности (там этого дерьма наблюдал выше крыши: как привлеченный админ), чем для банков... Как-то так.  А ср*ть хотят вышестоящие IT-шники из ГО, а не я - мне-то жить с этим самодуром.

Comment: @Justicet, у вас розовые очки. В банках всё плохо с софтом, персоналом и прочим. Я не имея офиц допуска как админ подрядчика помогал какую-то нашу софтину запихивать в банк, так наш софт был ужасен, но то с чем мы его скрещивали был просто кошмарен, одно межпроцессовое общение построенное поверх windows messaging service. чего стоит. почему так - потому что продавая банку конторам* не стыдно взять много (это же банк!)* некогда делать хорошо (бюрократия жрет много)* незачем делать хорошо (главное побольше воды налить про супершифрование)

Comment: а почему не выписать мне было офиц допуск ? всё просто - это банк. Такой запрос подобный из требований безопасности займет несколько дней, в лучшем случае, а работы там на 20 минут. Сроки у всех горят.

Comment: про сроки - согласен. В моем бы случае Вы так же СОВМЕСТНО (под наблюдением) занимались допиливанием (правда на тестовом сервере :Р) Тем и хорош был наш банк, что с политиками безопасности у нас все было в норме. Теперь же, после того как нас продали другому банку, мы столкнулись с такой задницей... (по известным соображениям названий не даю)  Розовых очков у меня нет, у нас софтом все было нормально.

Answer (score 0):

:) Поверьте, уважаемый, если к вам придёт хороший профессионал с целью навредить - то он навредит. Я лично не видел сеток, которые настроены идеально. В любой большой организации дыры в сети есть. Даже если админ этой сети - параноик и боится даже собственных пальцев. Тут человеческий фактор. Например, у директора одного из банков есть доступ ко всем возможным базам данных и информации в его банке. Ему, конечно же, админ порекомендует установить хороший длиннющий пароль. Но директору просто лень его набирать. И директор требует (именно требует, а не просит) нарушить все нормы информационной безопасности и сделать ему пустой пароль. И вы думаете, что админ будет препятствовать? Да сделает он пустой пароль, никуда не денется, нафига ему конфликт с директором. Ну а последствия.... Да придумайте самые страшные. Но я думаю, что страшнее, чем полная потеря информации, просто не бывает.